# Difference between (FILE*)fp and fp in fgets?

Tags: c

I have been looking up some examples of reading from a file in C and I see both

```
fgets(buff,255,(FILE*)fp);
```

and

```
fgets(buff,255,fp);
```

assuming fp is the file pointer defined earlier "`FILE *fp;`"

Is there any difference in this at all? or does the compiler just convert one to another?

Also I notice in some "While" loops that read the entire file, some say while(fgets(buff,255,fp)) (so assuming while it's true) and some will specifically check while(fgets(buff,255,fp)!= NULL).

Shouldn't the "true" one fail? since it returns the buff if it succeeds and null if it fails?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-null pointer is treated as true in a conditional statement. Therefore,

```
while(fgets(buff,255,fp))
```

is equivalent to

```
while(fgets(buff,255,fp)!=NULL)
```

Also, the `(FILE*)fp` is a typecast. Since `fp` is already declared as `FILE *fp;` the cast has no effect.